# How to match this pattern (with emoji)?

Tags: regex, text, emoji

I have a text file of a few thousand entries built like that:

> 11111111111: text text text text text :: word11111111: text text text text :: word111111111:

Where:

- `11111111` is a big number
- `text text text text` can be `anything` including emoji
- `word` is one of 8 words
- the second `111111111` is another number, but different.

I tried, but just couldn't match it.

I don't know how to treat the emoji, and another problem is the spaces are not consistent, sometimes is a whitespace, sometimes tab, and so on.

Comment: What regexes have you tried?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What about [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/lB7kE5/1)?

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
^([0-9]+):\s*((?:(?!\s::).)*)\s::\s*([^:]+)\s*:\s*((?:(?!\s::).)*)\s::\s*([^:]+):$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Capture the leading `11111111`
- Match the `:`
- Capture the `text text text text text` which may contain emojis.
- Match the `::`
- Capture the `word11111111`
- match the `:`
- Capture the `text text text text text` which may contain emojis.
- Match the `::`
- Capture the `word11111111`
- Match the `:`
- Allow the `:` or `::` to be delimiters
- Do not include the spaces surrounding the delimiters to be included in the matches.

To see the image better, you can right click it and select open in new window

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/qG7uZ7/1

**Sample text**

```
11111111111: text text text text text :: word11111111: text text text text :: word111111111:
```

**Capture Groups from match**

```
0.  11111111111: text text text text text :: word11111111: text text text text :: word111111111:
1.  `11111111111`
2.  `text text text text text`
3.  `word11111111`
4.  `text text text text`
5.  `word111111111`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ::                       '::'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ::                       '::'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ::                       '::'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ::                       '::'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```